Problems with my RTW89_8852BE wifi network driver, I can't connect to the wifi network (Lenovo Ideapad 3 PC)
I'm new to Ubuntu and I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15ABA7 with AMD ryzen 5 processor. I've been struggling for days with my wifi network driver and I lost. At first I got an error when activating the network connection, after installing your drivers I could see the networks but they wouldn't connect, the networks keep loading and never finish connecting. I would love some advice please. Here is some information:
New drivers installed: A repo for the newest Realtek rtw89 codes.
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install

Unload/reload a Kernel module:
sudo modprobe -rv rtw_8852be
sudo modprobe -rv rtw89core      #These two statements unload the module

Due to the behavior of the modprobe utility, it takes both to unload.

sudo modprobe -v rtw_8852be          #This loads the module

A single modprobe call will reload the module.
Restart Network Management: sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Module firmware verification:
sudo systemctl status wpa_supplicant
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-10-22 21:43:19 -03; 12s ago
   Main PID: 7607 (wpa_supplicant)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 11567)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 190ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
             └─7607 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

oct 22 21:43:19 Elian-PC systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
oct 22 21:43:19 Elian-PC wpa_supplicant[7607]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
oct 22 21:43:19 Elian-PC systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
oct 22 21:43:29 Elian-PC wpa_supplicant[7607]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending

sudo dmesg | grep firmware
[    0.089427] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    3.326635] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x0101001F
[    3.327112] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.21 DEC: 7 VEP: 0 Revision: 3
[    3.327120] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    6.812866] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware rtw89/rtw8852b_fw-1.bin
[ 1335.507411] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware rtw89/rtw8852b_fw-1.bin

Network information:
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
    Kernel modules: rtw_8852be

sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlp2s0
       versión: 00
       serie: e0:0a:f6:ae:fc:17
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=6.8.0-47-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:75 ioport:2000(size=256) memoria:fd600000-fd6fffff
  *-network
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       id físico: 8
       nombre lógico: enxe00af6aefc18
       serie: e0:0a:f6:ae:fc:18
       capacidades: ethernet physical
       configuración: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.162 multicast=yes

Errors in the driver system log:
sudo dmesg | grep rtw
[    6.704622] rtw89core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
**Is there the problem? -->** [    6.704627] rtw89core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel 
[    6.812866] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware rtw89/rtw8852b_fw-1.bin
[    6.813007] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    6.816542] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 0.29.29.5 (da87cccd), cmd version 0, type 5
[    6.816560] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 0.29.29.5 (da87cccd), cmd version 0, type 3
[    7.126587] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: chip rfe_type is 1
[    7.188418] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 1335.507411] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware rtw89/rtw8852b_fw-1.bin
[ 1335.509472] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 0.29.29.5 (da87cccd), cmd version 0, type 5
[ 1335.509479] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 0.29.29.5 (da87cccd), cmd version 0, type 3
[ 1335.806538] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: chip rfe_type is 1
[ 1335.847370] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0

Ubuntu:
sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

kernel:
uname -a
Linux Elian-PC 6.8.0-47-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Oct  2 16:16:55 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

BIOS:
sudo dmidecode | grep -A3 '^BIOS Information'
BIOS Information
    Vendor: LENOVO
    Version: JTCN26WW
    Release Date: 02/17/2022


Once you have started trying to build and install your own drivers, it's usually too late to troubleshoot, I'm afraid. Standard practise is: [1] Connect to Ethernet, not wifi. [2] Do a full update. [3] Reboot, try again. [4] Run the Ubuntu drivers tool and check for optional drivers. Install all available. [5] Reboot again, try again.

Yes, the highlight part of your log in your question suggested the driver you have built is not signed. This is turn suggests you are running secure boot. You could try turning off secure boot (with security consequences) and see if it works. If it does you will need to sign the executable with a 'mokkey'

Why not cd rtw89 && sudo make uninstall  reboot andpost results for sudo dmesg |grep rtw
